# How to make a Hirarchical Json Structure with java program

Tags: java, json, gson

I am working on a generation JSON. The desired result is:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "name": "Jeet123",
            "type": 1,
            "slug": "",
            "entity": "company"
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 1,
            "value": 1,
            "distance": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

This JSON i have to make. I am Writing this java code.. But it only shows {}

`Entry1`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

class Entry1 {

private String name;
private int type;
private String slug;
private String entity;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getSlug() {
    return slug;
}

public void setSlug(String slug) {
    this.slug = slug;
}

public String getEntity() {
    return entity;
}

public void setEntity(String entity) {
    this.entity = entity;
}
}
```

`Entry2`:

```
class Entry2 {

private String source;
private String target;
private String value;
private String distance;

public String getSource() {
    return source;
}

public void setSource(String source) {
    this.source = source;
}

public String getTarget() {
    return target;
}

public void setTarget(String target) {
    this.target = target;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(String distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}
}
```

`EntryListContainer`:

```
class EntryListContainer {

public List<Entry1> nodes;
public List<Entry2> links;

public void setEntryList1(List<Entry1> entryList1) {
    this.nodes = nodes;
}

public List<Entry1> getEntryList1() {

    return nodes;
}

public void setEntryList2(List<Entry2> entryList1) {
    this.links = links;
}

public List<Entry2> getEntryList2() {

    return links;
}

}
```

`LinkJson`:

```
public class LinkJson {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EntryListContainer container = new EntryListContainer();

    List<Entry1> entryList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Entry2> entryList2 = new ArrayList<>();

    Entry1 entry1 = new Entry1();

    entry1.setName("Jeet123");
    entry1.setType(1);
    entry1.setSlug("");
    entry1.setEntity("company");

    entryList1.add(entry1);

    Entry2 entry2 = new Entry2();

    entry2.setSource("0");
    entry2.setTarget("1");
    entry2.setValue("1");
    entry2.setDistance("5");

    entryList2.add(entry2);

    container.setEntryList1(entryList1);
    container.setEntryList2(entryList2);

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(container));

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad copy/paste !

```
public void setEntryList2(List<Entry2> entryList1) {
        this.links = links;
    }

    public void setEntryList1(List<Entry1> entryList1) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }
```

You should have this :

```
public void setEntryList2(List<Entry2> links) {
    this.links = links;
}

public void setEntryList1(List<Entry1> nodes) {
    this.nodes = nodes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Constructor for your  `EntryListContainer` class:

```
class EntryListContainer {

    private List<Entry1> nodes;
    private List<Entry2> links;

    public EntryListContainer(List<Entry1> nodes, List<Entry2> links) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
        this.links = links;
    }
}
```

And then create the `container` object this way:

```
EntryListContainer container = new EntryListContainer(entryList1,entryList2);
```

And then create the json:

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();

  System.out.println(gson.toJson(container));
```

**Edit**: Not necessary to use the constructor,

Change the following methods in your `EntryListContainer` class and it will work:

```
public void setEntryList1(List<Entry1> entryList1) {
        this.nodes = entryList1;
    }

public void setEntryList2(List<Entry2> entryList2) {
        this.links = entryList2;
    }
```

Comment: Why is using a constructor different from using setters?

Comment: @Jhanvi would you be upset if I correct the typos in the code in the body of your answer?  In both your setter methods, the parameter name doesn't match the actual use of the argument, which means the setter actually does nothing.

Comment: Oh you actually removed them?  I thought it made sense to leave them there, but just correct them.

Answer (score 1):

The way JSON is usually parsed to get the properties is to find the property names (`nodes` and `links` in your code) and then capitalise the first letter and append the `get` word onto the front to try and use the getter method. Basically your `EntryListContainer` doesn't follow the [Java Bean Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) that JSON (and GSON by proxy) relies on.
So it didn't print anything because you had no getter method for `getNodes` or `getLinks`, you have `getEntryList1` and `getEntryList2`

I'm pretty sure you EntryListContainer class needs to look like this:

```
class EntryListContainer {

    public List<Node> nodes;
    public List<Link> links;

    public void setNodes(final List<Node> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }

    public List<Node> getNodes() {
        return this.nodes;
    }

    public void setLinks(final List<Link> links) {
        this.links = links;
    }

    public List<Link> getLinks() {
        return this.links;
    }

}
```